# How to disable character escaping by jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I want to include html in my JSON response.

```
MyClass obj= new MyCLass();
obj.setHTML("<div style='display:none'>4</div>");

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

String jsonResponse=mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
System.out.println(jsonResponse);
```

O/P i get

```
{"html":"<div style=\"display:none\">4</div>"}
```

Required O/P

```
{"html":"<div style='display:none'>4</div>"}
```

Since I want to use the json response directly. Can i disable the escaping of qoutes by object mapper.

Answer (score 10):

You can annotate your getHtml method with

```
@JsonRawValue
```